# How to check if a database query has results?

Tags: 7, database

How do I check if the following code has results?

I tried the *empty* function but it always returns *FALSE*

```
$query = db_select('my_table', 't');
$query->condition('code', 10)
      ->fields('t', array('cid'));
$result = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I'm correct the result of the execute() call should be a [DatabaseStatementInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/interface/DatabaseStatementInterface/7) which has a [rowCount](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3a%3arowCount/7) function.

Comment: Indeed, the following gives the number of results: `var_dump($result->rowCount());`

Answer (score 1):

If you print `var_dump($result);` you will see that `$result` contains the query and other variables so it's never empty.
You can put `$result` in a `foreach` loop to see the results.

```
foreach ($result as $record) {
  var_dump($record);
}
```

Inside the `foreach` loop, you can print the results with this code.

```
foreach ($result as $record) {
  print $record->nid;
  print $record->title;
}
```

If there is only one record as result use [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to handle the record.

Comment: You have a typo. This should be `foreach ($result as $record) { var_dump($record); }`

Comment: With Drupal, it's a bad advice to suggest using a MySQL function. The site could be using PosgreSQL, SQLite, or another database engine with which Drupal is compatible. Drupal database functions don't require a module to know the database engine used from the side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
print_r($record);
}
```